# Contains.(cs) is case sensitive in android

Tags: java, android

I have a search method written onTextChanged. This will search an Arraylist of Hashmap. The problem here is that I get search results only for upper case or lower case.

How to solve this issue by making it not case sensitive.

Here is the code I have:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            song = 2;
            songsList2.clear();

            for (HashMap<String, String> map : songsList)
            {

                if(map.get(KEY_TITLE).contains(s))
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map2.put(KEY_ID, map.get(KEY_ID));
                    map2.put(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                    map2.put(KEY_ARTIST, map.get(KEY_ARTIST));
                    map2.put(KEY_DURATION, map.get(KEY_DURATION));
                    map2.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    songsList2.add(map2);   
                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(CustomizedListView.this, songsList2);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `contains` method is case sensitive. If you want to make it not so, you can either compile a regex pattern and use that instead, or simply make the value you search to lowercase and then check it, just as

`if(map.get(KEY_TITLE).toLowerCase().contains(s)...`

assuming that the `char` sequence is in the same case.

**Edit**:
As pointed out in the comments, to ensure a match where no assumption of the `char` sequence case is made, you would have to force the search phrase to the same case by using `toLowerCase` on it aswell

`if(map.get(KEY_TITLE).toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())...`

Comment: "assuming that the char sequence is in the same case" : I think that's the main problem. You're approach is sound but ideally both need to be forced to the same case, i.e., also need to use `contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())` instead of just `contains(s)`

Comment: The problem is few strings are in this format: "John David" and a few are "john david" - so if I have search with char "J" first I get only John David... so how do I make only the first character to by Uppercase?

Comment: @TheDevMan : See my comment above. If you force both `s` and the returned string from `map.get(...)` into the same case then it should work.

Comment: @Squonk: As per your comment I tried the following: if(map.get(KEY_TITLE).contains(s) || contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) - I am getting the results. I guess this what you recommended right?

Answer (score 1):

First avoid using concrete classes when you can use interfaces. As far as I understand `songsList` is a list or arrays of `HashMap`s. Change the definition to `List<Map<String, String>>`. Now use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` but pass `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` comparator when creating the instance:

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Now you do not need to change your code. you can put there "Yellow Submarine" and get either "yellow submarine" or "YELLOW SUBMARINE" or whatever. But the actual value stored in map remains "Yellow Submarine" (the value that you put), so if you iterate over the entries you get "correct" value.